# how do i make hazelcast to store in my database using MapStore implementation

Tags: java, hazelcast

I implemented `MapStore` and configured hazelcast (v 2.2) so that it would know that when calling `map.put()` it has to call in background `.store` from my implementation, at least that`s what i read.

If i use my implementation directly it does store what I want but if I call `map.put()` it doesn't.
Can someone tell me why it doesn't or if i`m doing something wrong?

here is my `MapStore` implementation:

```
public class MyMapStore implements MapStore<String, Object> {

private Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();

@Override
public Object load(String key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> loadAll(Collection<String> keys) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Set<String> loadAllKeys() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void store(String key, Object value) {
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save((MyObject)value);
    tx.commit();
}

@Override
public void storeAll(Map<String, Object> map) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void delete(String key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void deleteAll(Collection<String> keys) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Hazelcast configuration:

```
h.getConfig().getMapConfig("default").setMapStoreConfig(
    new MapStoreConfig().setEnabled(true).setClassName(
    MyMapStore.class.getName()).setWriteDelaySeconds(0));
```

Printing the hazelcast configuration tells that all I set is there so I don't know what`s wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I think something is missing in your hazelcast config. You need to create your "default" MapConfig. Here is a working example.

```
Config config = new Config();

    ....


MapConfig mapCfg = new MapConfig();
mapCfg.setName("default");
mapCfg.setBackupCount(2);
mapCfg.getMaxSizeConfig().setSize(10000);
mapCfg.setTimeToLiveSeconds(300);

MapStoreConfig mapStoreCfg = new MapStoreConfig();
mapStoreCfg.setClassName(MyMapStore.class.getName()).setEnabled(true);
mapCfg.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreCfg);

// use near cache if needed
NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig();
nearCacheConfig.setMaxSize(1000).setMaxIdleSeconds(120).setTimeToLiveSeconds(300);
mapCfg.setNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);

config.addMapConfig(mapCfg);

Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```